# Simplyfing Probability equation

Tags: summation, factorial

I was solving a homework problem, and I had obtained a formula for the required probability in the question.
 What I wanted to ask could it be more simplified?
$$P = \sum_{i=0}^{a}( \frac{a!}{(a-i)!} * \frac{(s-i-1)!}{s!})$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is in fact $P=1/(s-a)$.  Here's why.

Rewrite the sum as

$$\begin{align} P &= \frac{a!}{s!} \sum_{i=0}^a \frac{(s-i-1)!}{(a-i)!} \\ &= \frac{a!}{s!} \sum_{i=0}^a \frac{i}{s-i} \frac{(s-i)!}{(a-i)!} \\ &= \frac{a!}{s!} \sum_{i=0}^a \frac{1}{s-a+i} \frac{(s-a+i)!}{i!} \\ &= \frac{1}{\binom{s}{a}} \sum_{i=0}^a  \frac{1}{s-a+i} \binom{s-a+i}{i} \\ &= \frac{1}{\binom{s}{a}} \frac{1}{s-a} \underbrace{\sum_{i=0}^a \binom{s-a-1+i}{i}}_{\text{This is a well-known sum}}\\ &= \frac{1}{\binom{s}{a}} \frac{1}{s-a} \binom{s}{a} \\ &=\frac{1}{s-a} \end{align}$$

The well-known sum may be found in, for example, *Concrete Mathematics* by Knuth, Graham, and Patashnik, Second Ed., p. 161.

Answer (score 4):

It could be more simplified in this way: 
$$P = \frac{a!}{s!} \sum_{i=0}^{a}\frac{(s-i-1)!}{(a-i)!}$$
not more

Comment: I believe that the sum may be expressed as $\sum_{i=0}^{a}\frac{(s-i-1)!}{(a-i)!}=\frac{(s-1) (s-2)!}{(s-a) (a-1)!}$

Comment: Could you please give a proof for your statement.

Comment: The word 'believe' should have been expanded to 'I took a guess and verified it for a few values of $a$ with $s$ fixed'. I would love to give a proof, but no guarantee as to how quickly I may conjure one up. (I guess that's why I left it as a comment rather than a new answer.)

Comment: And would not it become $\frac{(s-1)!}{(s-a)(a-1)!}$

Comment: I realize now that I was verifying my identity with a sum indexed at 1 instead of 0. My error.

Comment: If your formula for index = 1 is correct then $P = \frac{a!}{s!}*(\frac{(s-1)!}{a!} + \frac{(s-1)!}{(s-a)(a-1)!})$ $$=> P = \frac{1}{(s-a)}$$